# How to make time slot in R

Tags: r

Guys would you help me out to make a time slot of my data?

I have following data sets

```
Name      Arrival Time  
Ron       00:30
John      16:45
Sam       14:59
```

I want to include time slots for each arrival time,

```
Name      Arrival Time        Time Slot
Ron       00:30               00:00-01:00
John      16:45               16:00-17:00
Sam       14:59               14:00-15:00
```

How to do it in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a strategy:

```
arrival <- c('00:30','16:45','14:59')
a2 <- as.POSIXlt(arrival,'%H:%M',tz='')
paste(format(a2,'%H:00'),format(a2+3600,'%H:00'),sep='-')
[1] "00:00-01:00" "16:00-17:00" "14:00-15:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach where I treat the time as full datetime and keep them in that format:

```
arrivalString <- c("00:30", "16:45", "14:59")
arrival <- strptime(arrivalString, format = "%H:%M")
names <-  c("Ron", "John", "Sam")
df <- data.frame(names, arrival)

slotbegin <- as.POSIXlt(df$arrival)
slotbegin$min <-rep(0, length(slotbegin))
df <- cbind(df, slotbegin)

slotend <- as.POSIXlt(df$arrival)
slotend$min <- rep(0, length(slotend))
slotend$hour <- slotend$hour + 1
df <- cbind(df, slotend)
```

Output:

```
  names             arrival           slotbegin             slotend
1   Ron 2013-10-09 00:30:00 2013-10-09 00:00:00 2013-10-09 01:00:00
2  John 2013-10-09 16:45:00 2013-10-09 16:00:00 2013-10-09 17:00:00
3   Sam 2013-10-09 14:59:00 2013-10-09 14:00:00 2013-10-09 15:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `as.Date` and `strftime`

```
a <- "00:15"
astart <- paste(
   strftime(
      as.Date(
         a,
         "%H:%M"
      ),
      "%H"
   ),
   ":00",
   sep = ""
)

a <- "00:15"
aend <- paste(
   as.integer(
      strftime(
      as.Date(
         a,
         "%H:%M"
      ),
      "%H"
      )
   ) + 1,
":00",
sep = ""
)
```

Output:

```
> astart
[1] "00:00"
> aend
[1] "1:00"
```